# Eigenvectors of Vandermonde-like matrices

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $\mathbf{x} = (x_0, \cdots, x_n), \mathbf{y} = (y_0, \cdots, y_n)$ be integer vectors. Form the Vandermonde-type matrix

$$\displaystyle V(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) = \begin{bmatrix} x_0^n & x_0^{n-1} y_0 & \cdots & y_0^n \\ x_1^n & x_1^{n-1} y_1 & \cdots & y_1^n \\ \vdots & \ddots & \cdots & \vdots \\ x_n^n & x_n^{n-1} & \cdots & y_n^n \end{bmatrix}.$$
That is, the $ij$-th entry of $V(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})$ is equal to $x_i^{n-j} y_i^j$ for $0 \leq i, j \leq n$.

For a fixed pair $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}$ let $S(\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b})$ be the set of pairs of vectors $(\mathbf{a}^\prime, \mathbf{b}^\prime)$, both in $\mathbb{Z}^{n+1}$, such that the vector $(1, \cdots, 1)^T$ is a (right) eigenvector of the matrix $V(\mathbf{a}^\prime, \mathbf{b}^\prime) V(\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b})^{-1}$.

An obvious subset of $S(\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b})$ is given as follows: for any $M \in \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, the tuple $(\mathbf{a}^\prime(M), \mathbf{b}^\prime(M))$ given by

$$\begin{bmatrix} a_j^\prime(M) \\ b_j^\prime(M) \end{bmatrix} = M \begin{bmatrix} a_j \\ b_j \end{bmatrix} \text{ for } 0 \leq j \leq n$$

lies in $S(\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b})$. More generally, we can take $M \in \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$, provided that the vectors $\mathbf{a}^\prime(M), \mathbf{b}^\prime(M) \in \mathbb{Z}^{n+1}$. Call these the trivial solutions.

My question is this: for a fixed pair $(\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b})$, how do we find the non-trivial elements in $S(\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b})$, or else show that only trivial solutions exist?